# Authenticate to Azure Functions App using Azure Active Directory in Python daemon application with MSAL

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal

I built a REST API by creating an Azure Functions App and a Python console application should be able to authenticate and make requests to the API.
Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. I created the REST API as an Azure Functions App (in C#) where I used *AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous*.
2. In the Azure Active Directory I created an app registration (Azure Active Directory > App registrations) where I added a client secret under Certificates & secrets > Client secrets.
3. In the Azure Functions App I added the registration from step 2 under Authentication > Identity provider where I provided the registration's client ID as well as the value of the registration's client secret.
4. Here is the code of the Python console application (as described here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python):

```
import requests
import msal
import json


with open('configuration.json') as json_file:
    configuration = json.load(json_file)

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    configuration["client_id"],
    authority=configuration["authority"],
    client_credential=configuration["secret"]
    )

result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(configuration["scope"],account=None)
if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=configuration["scope"])   

if "access_token" in result:
    url = ... # the URL of a specific function of the Azure Functions App
    parameters = {...} 
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=parameters, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})

    print("Status code: {}".format(response.status_code))
    print("Message: {}".format(response.text))
```

*registration["scope"]* equals *["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]* and *registration["secret"]* equals the value of the client secret created in step 2.

The code returns:
Status code: 401
Message: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

What am I missing? I know there are similar issues on Stackoverflow but they did not solve my problem.

Comment: Which kind of authentication you are using now? classic or newest? Newest have some bugs now. Have you check the issue page url? v2 or v1?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the newest authentication, please check the issue url:

Check your Issuer URL:

[image]

[image]

Or to change the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2:

[image]

Any way, make sure the issue url version is the same.

(I found there are still many problems with Authentication, and many things will not be automatically configured.)